# Add keywords to an ArrayCollection Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am creating an ArrayCollection through a loop and afterwards want to use this ArrayCollection to build a line chart. The only problem is that I have only values in my ArrayCollection and no keywords, which are used to build a line chart. How can I add keywords to my ArrayCollection? Or is there a way to build a linechart without keywords?

here is the code of creating the arraycollection:

```
[Bindable] public var Graph_:ArrayCollection;

        public function populateArray():void {

        var Graph_:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        for (var i:int=0; i<=500; i++){

            var depth_:Number = i*10;
            var pressure:Number = 100+i;
            Graph_.addItem([depth_,pressure]); 

            }
// I want to use it further in this way:

<mx:LineChart id="chart"
          dataProvider= "{Graph_}"
          showDataTips="true">

    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="Depth" />   
    </mx:horizontalAxis>

    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries  yField="Pressure" form="curve" displayName="Pressure"/>
    </mx:series>

    </mx:LineChart>
```

Comment: Create an object, add your fields to it, add the objects to the arrayCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what @Brian Bishop suggested you do:

```
public function populateArray():void {

    Graph_ = new ArrayCollection();
    for (var i:int=0; i<=500; i++) {

        var depth_:Number = i*10;
        var pressure:Number = 100+i;
        // add an object who's property names are "depth", "pressure"
        // use these names when configuring the axis/line series of the chart
        Graph_.addItem({ depth: depth_, pressure: pressure }); 
    }
}
```

When you add items to the `ArrayCollection`, add them as anonymous Object's that contain your data. Now you can tell your chart to use these "keywords" (property names).

NOTE: I also changed this line: `Graph_ = new ArrayCollection();`

Your code was using a local `Graph_` variable that only existed inside the function, it wasn't the `[Bindable] Graph_` variable you defined in the class.